# Improve this code by eliminating nested for cycles

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, functional-programming, apply

The R package `corrplot` contains, among the other stuff, this nifty function

```
cor.mtest <- function(mat, conf.level = 0.95){
  mat <- as.matrix(mat)
    n <- ncol(mat)
    p.mat <- lowCI.mat <- uppCI.mat <- matrix(NA, n, n)
    diag(p.mat) <- 0
    diag(lowCI.mat) <- diag(uppCI.mat) <- 1
    for(i in 1:(n-1)){
        for(j in (i+1):n){
            tmp <- cor.test(mat[,i], mat[,j], conf.level = conf.level)
            p.mat[i,j] <- p.mat[j,i] <- tmp$p.value
            lowCI.mat[i,j] <- lowCI.mat[j,i] <- tmp$conf.int[1]
            uppCI.mat[i,j] <- uppCI.mat[j,i] <- tmp$conf.int[2]
        }
    }
    return(list(p.mat, lowCI.mat, uppCI.mat))
}
```

which computes the p-values and confidence intervals for the pairwise correlations among variables `x_1,...,x_n`, given `N` observations of the `n` variables. The function takes a numeric matrix in input, and returns a `list` whose 3 elements are 3 `nxn` symmetric matrices: that's why, inside the nested `for` loops, only the upper diagonal parts of the 3 matrices are computed. Example:

```
res1 <- cor.mtest(mtcars,0.95)
> str(res1)
List of 3
 $ : num [1:11, 1:11] 0.00 6.11e-10 9.38e-10 1.79e-07 1.78e-05 ...
 $ : num [1:11, 1:11] 1 -0.926 -0.923 -0.885 0.436 ...
 $ : num [1:11, 1:11] 1 -0.716 -0.708 -0.586 0.832 ...
```

I think (and I may be wrong) that `for` loops are not very idiomatic in R: I see a lot of code where people substitute them with the `map` family of function from     `purr`, or the `apply` family of function from `base`. I would like to eliminate the two `for` loops with such functional programming functions. Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: For loops are only evil if a) they operate on growing non-allocated in advance object or b) are used instead of already vectorized function. Here all is fine: a) is taken care of with `matrix(NA, n, n)`, b) is also not an issue. Moreover, replacing with `*apply` here will make that little optimization with upper diagonal look very clumsy. So for this particular case I'd recommend sticking to the original code. If you need performance, translate the loop via Rcpp (another benefit of for: porting to c++ is easy).

Comment: @tonytonov thanks for the suggestion, then I'll keep the code as it is